# CSS Image Sizing using Media Queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries, image-resizing

Hey I have been trying to create media queries for a website I developed. I have encountered a problem where when I resize an image in my media queries, it adjusts the border, however the full image size stays the same.[Example of this shown in this link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71WkH.jpg)

For the first image on that page, I have used these CSS properties for media queries.

```
#working {
        float: left;
        margin: 0px auto;
        border: 2px solid #000000;
        width: 175px; 
        height: 175px;
        display: block;
}
```

For the non- media queries I have used this CSS code:

```
#working {
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 215px 10px 110px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    width: 350px; 
    height: 350px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Please provide html as well. Have you checked size of the div or parent div of these images.

Comment: I would also like to position in the center

Answer (score 0):

The solution to you problem is simple. To get the image to adjust properly, do the following.

1. Wrap the image a div or HTML5 figure (Set overflew property value 
   to hidden)
2. set the image to always fit the wrapper
3. Image height or width should be 100%, while the other is auto
4. Adjust the the image wrapper at your desired break-point

Note: I believe that the reason for your issue is that the image is overlapping.

- Run the snippet in the full window mode, then adjust window width to see the code in action.

```css
#image-wrapper {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
overflow: hidden; /* Hide overlapping part of the imager */
border: 5px solid red; /* Just show that the image is controled */
transition: all .7s; /* Just to make the adjustment smooth */
}

#image-wrapper img {
width: 100%;
height: auto; /* Allows the image to adjust properly */
transition: all .7s;
}


/* Now see what happens when the device or screen is less that 601px */

@media only screen and (max-width: 601px) {

#image-wrapper {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin: auto; /* This should position it in the center */
transition: all .7s;
}

}
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">   
<div id="image-wrapper">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/71WkH.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be necessary that you post your full CSS and HTML in order to give you a reliable answer which you really can rely on.

However, if you are using the CSS in the order that you posted it (media query rules first, *then* general rules) the answer is simple: The general rules will always overwrite the media query rules since the follow later and apply to *all* screen sizes. To avoid that, list the gereral rules first and then the media queries.

Comment: I am guessing you voted my answer down. If yes, can you please let me know why so that I can learn.